# what would be needed for a sword that glows?

Tags: science-based, physics, geology

how would it be possible for a sword that glows  a very dim light at all times.  What materials would be needed to do this?  would this hamper the effectiveness of the blade?

Comment: So your looking for a radio active sword?  Or do you just want one that is coated in the same sort of phosphors that childrens toys use to glow in the dark?  This link might help, https://www.wonderopolis.org/wonder/how-do-things-glow-in-the-dark

Comment: light requires energy if you want it to glow all the time you need a power source.

Comment: No not radioactive i dont want it to harm the user  just  something that glows at all times .Yes kinda like children toys  but I know that forging that into the sword would make it lose the properties  that would make a child's toy  glow and constantly coating it isnt what im looking for.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1114/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of options, some better than others. Since you did not specify the tech level, I'll assume modern technology.

- **Solar and LED-lights**

Slap some small, robust solar panels to the flat side of the blade, put a rechargeable battery into the handle and place LED's all over the sword. Might looks more like a Cyberpunk sex toy or cos play implement than an actual weapon, but if you design it carefully the light feature should not diminish the blades effectiveness greatly.

- **ATOMIC sword**

In 1987 a Brazilian girl painted her face with blue glowing paint she had found inside a Maschine in an abandoned hospital. She died of radiation poisoning some time later. 
The is known as the [Goiânia accident](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goi%C3%A2nia_accident) and the "glowing paint" was a small capsule containing about 93 grams (3.3 oz) of highly radioactive caesium chloride (a caesium salt made with a radioisotope, caesium-137). It was used inside a medical device. Ceasium-137 chloride might be a good point to start with and I'm certain that there are other substances fitting the bill. You could either paint the blade with them or work them into the blade. I do love the idea of a sword which gives the Chosen One cancer and makes the Chernobyl incident look environmentally benign by comparison.

EDIT1: [This xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1114/) suggests Actinium for the blue glow and +2 cancer risk.

- **[Phosphorescent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence) or [Fluorescent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) Materials**

The difference between the two is that while fluorescent materials only glow while they are exposed to a lightsource, phosphorescent materials will emit the light slowly after the lightsource has been removed. The first blade would only glow in daylight, the second one would glow at night, too.

- **[Bioluminecence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescence)**

> Bioluminecence occurs widely in marine vertebrates and invertebrates, as well as in some fungi, microorganisms including some bioluminescent bacteria and terrestrial invertebrates such as fireflies. In some animals, the light is bacteriogenic, produced by symbiotic organisms such as Vibrio bacteria; in others, it is autogenic, produced by the animals themselves.

This gives us a lot to work with. Having a cavity in the sword in which some bioluminescencent fungi, microorganisms or bacteria live might look nicely. Feed them with the blood of your enemies. Or use an animal like an alien monster-firefly and build the blade around it. Genetic engineering should give you loads of options.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use [radium](https://www.britannica.com/science/radium):
`When a radium salt is mixed with a paste of zinc sul[ph]ide, the alpha radiation causes the zinc sul[ph]ide to glow, yielding a self-luminescent paint for watch, clock, and instrument dials.`
You could apply it as a paint during the hardening process, or during the actual forging, but the latter would probably get you a weaker blade

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why everyone thinks that swords have to be made of solid steel, with glowing stuff painted onto the metal or worked into it.

While glass or crystals such as diamonds are brittle, they are harder than steel and *translucent*, that is, they could *contain* something glowing in a hollow inside the blade. Materials science has recently developed many harder-than-steel and durable materials, such as (transparent) polycarbonates, treated [wood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BStJLI7WQ8g), , and silica nanofibres. Some of these materials aren't flexible enough or cannot be sharpened or are too flexible for swords, but they provide a direction in which to think (and research).

Hardness of an object not only depends on the hardness of the base material (e.g. a steel rod is harder than a tin rod), but can be greatly increased by aligning the atoms in a stronger structure, such as in this [stronger-than-steel material](https://www.livescience.com/57432-stronger-than-steel-material.html) made from graphene (the stuff in your pencils). The developers of that material say that its properties do not depend on the atoms used. We can easily imagine a blade *printed* from a

## 1. transparent material arranged in a gyroid microstructure

that is ***filled*** with something that glows, such as an electric light, phosphorescent fluid, or one of the other things suggested in the other answers.

But it is also already possible to create transparent metals such as an [optical ceramic](http://www.surmet.com/technology/alon-optical-ceramics/index.php) made from aluminum and used to create military armor. I'm not sure how brittle it is and if the edge of a sword blade made from this material would stay sharp after repeatedly beating it against a steel sword, but my suggestion would be a

## 2. transparent metal alloy

filled with glowing stuff.

But of course a metal sword can be made that glows. An incandescent light bulb contains a glowing metal wire, and we can easily imagine a sword blade made to glow from electricity. New materials such as

## 3. luminescent oligonuclear metal complexes

[glow like an LED](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010854517304836). As I understand it, these luminescent metal compounds need only very low voltage and can be used to build glowing objects (the scholarly arcticle were a bit too technical for me).

Apparently LED lamps can be [powered by body heat](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/this-flashlight-is-powered-by-the-touch-of-your-hand-180950226/), so your LED sword wouldn't even need a battery.

I once saw an informational children's tv show in which a man stood on a field holding a light bulb in his hand which glowed from the electromagnetic field of a nearby broadcasting tower. So if your sworld wielder lives in a highly electromagnetic area, the LED sword could glow through [wireless power transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer) (image shows Nicolas Tesla):

[image: Image of Nicolas Tesla holding light bulbs that glow from electromagnetism]